Is it possible to filter granchild navigation on parent navigation in EF Core
I have the following model:
public class Walk
{
    public Guid WalkId { get; set; }
    public int StoreNbr { get; set; }
    public StoreInformation StoreInformation { get; set; }
    public WalkTemplate Template { get; set; } = null!;
    public ICollection<WalkQuestionResult> WalkQuestionResults { get; set; } = new List<WalkQuestionResult>();
}

Walk has many Walk Templates
public class WalkTemplate
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Walk> Walks { get; set; }
    public ICollection<WalkQuestion> Questions { get; set; } = new List<WalkQuestion>();
    public ICollection<WalkTemplateQuestion> TemplateQuestions { get; set; }
}

Template has Many To Many Relationship with Walk Questions using a WalkTemplateQuestions join table
public class WalkQuestion 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<WalkTemplate> Templates { get; set; }
    public ICollection<WalkQuestionsCondition> Conditions { get; set; }
    public ICollection<WalkTemplateQuestion> TemplateQuestions { get; set; }
}

Questions have a one to many relationship with condition.
I want to pull in the Walk but only pull in the questions where they meet All conditions a store has I have a store conditions table that holds all the conditions.
So far I have tried this:
await _context.Walks
                .Include(w => w.Template)
                .ThenInclude(w => w.Questions.Where(q => q.Conditions.All(c => _context.WalkStoreAttributes.Where(s => s.StoreNbr == 16487).Select(a => a.Attribute).Contains(c.Condition))))
                .Include(w => w.CompletedByEmployee)
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync(w => w.WalkId == id);

This appears to produce the correct SQL which I think will limit the questiosn to only if the quetions have all the condions that are in WalkStoreAttributes. However I have to hard code the store number .
I would like to be able to refrence the StoreNbr from the parent ie:
_context.WalkStoreAttributes.Where(s => s.StoreNbr == Walk.StoreNbr)

Can you share parent and grandchild class?

It would help to have a [mre]. The description of model is not complete. Currently, the question can't be reproduced.

Re-wrote the questions with full model and exmaple

Walk has one walk Template is it?

Walk has one template. Template has many walks.

Yes it is totally possible. Just used back the parent lambda.
Assuming one parent will have only one child and one child will only have one grandchild :
  _context.Parent.Include(w => w.Child)
            .ThenInclude(t => t.Grandchild.Where(g => g.Conditions.Any(c => c.Condition.Contains(

_context.Parent.Single(h => h.Child.Grandchild == g).parentProps

)))


I have a a many to many relationship. I added more inforamtion for context.
